# __new__ irrationally creates generator

Tags: python, class, oop, metaprogramming, yield

I have a class that process array and based on the type wrap it with different class or makes a generator

**Coat** class decides what to do with argument

**Coating** is the core class

```
class Coat:
    def __new__(cls, array, dtype=np.float32):

        if isinstance(array, np.ndarray):
            print('Condition 1')
            template = dtype(Coating(array.shape) * 0 + array)
            return template

        if isinstance(array, (list,tuple, GeneratorType)):
            print('Condition 2')
            for item in array:
                yield dtype(Coating(item.shape) * 0 + item)

class Coating(np.ndarray):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if len(self.shape) < 2:
            raise Exception("Not accustomed for 1D")
    def ...
    ...
```

So when I try to trigger both conditions (condition 1 or condition 2)

```
iterable = Coat([np.zeros(shape = [20,35]),np.zeros(shape = [20,35]),np.zeros(shape = [20,35])])
print(iterable)
array = Coat(np.zeros(shape=[10,10]),dtype=np.uint8)
print(array)
```

it returns me generators:

```
<generator object Coat.__new__ at 0x7fc2b4410bf8>
<generator object Coat.__new__ at 0x7fc291b5ef10>
```

Nothing is printed in the **new**.

However, if I remove the generator creation, everything works

```
class Coat:
    def __new__(cls, array, dtype=np.float32):

        if isinstance(array, np.ndarray):
            print('Condition 1')
            template = dtype(Coating(array.shape) * 0 + array)
            return template
        if isinstance(array, (list,tuple, GeneratorType)):
            print('Condition 2')
```

then

```
Condition 2
None
Condition 1
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

How is it possible that **yield** inside **__new__** behaves so dominantly, that is to say, makes a mess even if it is inside a condition that is not triggered?

Comment: I dont think __new__ is the right tool for this job

Comment: It's unclear why you expected otherwise. Any function that yields on any branch returns a generator.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble What would be a good practise then?

Comment: It looks like you are just deciding between two different results—a function? __new__ is generally seen for metaprogramming. Functions can return classes and objects too though

Comment: `__new__` isn't necessarily for metaprogramming, but there's little reason for `Coat` to be a class when its `__new__` method never returns an instance of `Coat`; it may as well be an ordinary function. (Note, especially, that you never use the value of `cls` in the body, a sure sign that you are doing something unnecessarily complicated.)

Comment: Your function is a generator function, so of course it returns a generator. There is nothing "irrational" about this. And function defined with `yield` is a generator function. `return` is a valid construct in a generator function, which simply terminates it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How is it possible that `yield` inside `__new__` behaves so dominantly, that is to say, makes a mess even if it is inside a condition that is not triggered?

That's built into the Python language. The presence of `yield` in a function (anywhere in the function) automatically makes the function a generator function.

From the docs:

> ## [7.7. The yield statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-yield-statement)
>
> [...]
>
> Yield expressions and statements are only used when defining a [generator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator) function, and are only used in the body of the generator function. **Using yield in a function definition is sufficient to cause that definition to create a generator function instead of a normal function.**
>
> [...]

Note that also `return` in a generator function will behave a bit differently than in a normal function.

---

Also I think there are probably better ways to deal with such situations, for example using a simple function instead of a "class with `__new__`". But I don't know enough about your code to suggest a better or more suitable solution.

However if you just want to "make it work", you could also `yield` in the first branch:

```
class Coat:
    def __new__(cls, array, dtype=np.float32):
        if isinstance(array, np.ndarray):
            yield dtype(Coating(array.shape) * 0 + array)

        if isinstance(array, (list,tuple, GeneratorType)):
            for item in array:
                yield dtype(Coating(item.shape) * 0 + item)
```

Then `Coat.__new__` always returns as generator.